# Xcode stopped recognizing class types randomly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, xcode5

[image: Example of code randomly stopping to be recognized]

So out of the blue, just between compiles, my xcode started flaring up with errors that increased every time I opened a class.

We are using framework, Sparrow, and it suddenly stopped detecting any class from it.

I tried restarting, cleaning the project, and deleting it from the projects folder,removing and re-adding the framework.

When I click on a class 'it can't find', it opens up to the class it supposedly can't find.

The errors I get are "unknown type name: XXX" (which means obviously that it can't find where it exists).

Why this happend randomly between builds is beyond me, Im guessing its an xcode bug, but if anyone has run into this and has a solution I would greatly appreciate it!

**UPDATE**
To anyone who encounters this in the future the only way I got this working was deleting everything and doing an SVN checkout on the entire project.

Comment: Have you check that your class is listed on the Compile Sources (build Phases)?

Comment: Yes, and they are not red (as they would be if it couldn't find them, I've seen that before too).

Comment: Sorry, besides typos and classes not being properly imported to the VC, that was my best shot.

Comment: I'll bet you had a header file that ended badly, causing subsequent headers in a list of includes to be essentially ignored.  Have seen it several times.

Comment: any more suloutions :(

Answer (score 0):

I've had Xcode do this a few times. Try this:

Clean the project folder: Shift + alt + cmd + k 
Clean the project: shit + cmd + k

Restart Xcode. Try build again

Comment: Yea :( Tried this and no go. But at least I know this has happend to others. I suspect this is an xcode bug.